# unsure how to display results using getelementbyId // javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok so my code is below. Once the calculate price button is clicked, I want it to display the results beneath the button. ie. number of cars = CarNumber, type of car = CarType and the price of the car = CarPrice. I know this is probably super easy to do but I just cant get it to work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="Cars">
<h1>Car Sales</h1>
<p>Which type of car would you like (A, B or C)</p>
<input type="text" name="CarType"><br>
<p>how many cars would you like (1-100)</p>
<input type="text" name="CarNumber"><br>
<br>
<button onclick="return beginfunction()">Calculate Price</button>
<p id="message"></p>
<script src="car.js">   </script>
 </form>
 </body>
</font>
```

JavaScript:

```
function beginfunction() {
  var CarType = document.forms["Cars"]["CarType"].value;
  var CarNumber = document.forms["Cars"]["CarNumber"].value;
   var CarPrice;
   if ( !( CarType == 'A' || CarType == 'B' || CarType == 'C' ) ) {
    CarTypeError = "Invalid Car Type";
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = CarTypeError;
     return false;

  }


  {
      if (isNaN(CarNumber)) {
        CarNumberError = "Invalid Quantity Entered";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = CarNumberError;
          return false;
      }

  }
{
  if (CarNumber >0 && CarNumber <10)
  {

  }
   else
  CarError = "Invalid";
   document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = CarError;
  return false;
}
{
 if (CarType == 'A') {
    CarPrice = 30;
} else if (CarType == 'B') {
    CarPrice = 20;
}  else if (CarType == 'C'){
  CarPrice = 10;
 }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you use innerHTML is right, but there is some logic problems in your function, here is the refactored code:

```
function beginfunction() {
  var CarType = document.forms["Cars"]["CarType"].value;
  var CarNumber = document.forms["Cars"]["CarNumber"].value;
  var CarPrice;
  var message = "";

  if ( !( CarType == 'A' || CarType == 'B' || CarType == 'C' ) ) {
    message = "Invalid Car Type";
  }else{
    if (CarType == 'A') {
      CarPrice = 30;
    } else if (CarType == 'B') {
      CarPrice = 20;
    }  else if (CarType == 'C'){
      CarPrice = 10;
    }
    message = CarPrice;
  }

  if (isNaN(CarNumber)) {
    message = "Invalid Quantity Entered";
  }

  if (CarNumber >0 && CarNumber <10)
  {

  }
  else{
    message = "Invalid";
  }

  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
  return false;
}
```